# Search for matching content with several AND and OR conditions

Tags: python, python-re

I'm having a list of content="[...]" variables (str). That variable must match at least one of each value in these lists (**case insensitive**). Do you have advice on how to achieve that best?

> react_terms = ["reactjs", "react.js", "react"] (OR condition)
>
> AND
>
> python_terms = ["python", "django"] (OR condition)
>
> AND
>
> cities_countries = ["london", "UK"] (OR condition)

What I'm trying (not working)

```
for content_str in content:
    if content_str in any(react_terms) and any(python_terms) and any(cities_countries):
        print(content_str, "match!")
```

#### Example with data

```
content = [
    "Lorem Ipsum reactjs, python in London",
    "Lorem Ipsum reactjs, python in United States",
    "Lorem Ipsum Vue, python in London, UK",
]
```

##### Result

- `content[0]` matches

`content[1]` & `content[2]` do NOT match because:

- `content[1]` didn't match as it didn't include any `cities_countries` terms
- content[2] didn't match as it didn't include any `react_terms`

Comment: regex might not be suitable option for your problem. You can just check if the substring is there or not.

Comment: I added an example of what I tried. I should match at least one term in every list.

Comment: Not just the example, it'd be better if you add some data as well

Comment: Added some data with matching / not matching results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Initial response

If you want `content_str` to match exactly any of the items in the three lists, you could use:

```py
if content_str.lower() in (react_terms + python_terms +cities_countries):
  # Do stuff
```

The `any` function will not work the way you used it. It will return a boolean value. Specifically, `True` if any of the items in the argument evaluates to a truthy expression (which, in turn, non empty `str`s are). So, the code you have written would be similar to:

```py
if content_str in True and content_str in True and content_str in True:
  #...
```

One last comment: if you do not plan on changing the items in the lists dinamically, it will be more efficient to just construct the "all items" list once:

```py
ITEMS_TO_MATCH = react_terms + python_terms +cities_countries
if content_str.lower() in ITEMS_TO_MATCH:
  # Do stuff
```

Note: I have ignored the `and` operators you tried to use as, with the data you have provided, there is no items that is on the three lists. If you actually plan to have items on both three lists, and you want to do stuff if `content_str` is in all theee lists, just recalculate `ITEMS_TO_MATCH` as such:

```py
ITEMS_TO_MATCH = [item for item in react_terms if item in python_terms and item in cities_countries]
```

## Edit

Now that you have provided some sample data I can more clearly understand what you are trying to do. Here is a scripts that meets you requirements:

```py
from typing import Iterable

CONTENT = [
    "Lorem Ipsum reactjs, python in London",
    "Lorem Ipsum reactjs, python in United States",
    "Lorem Ipsum Vue, python in London, UK",
]

CITIES_COUNTRIES = ("london", "UK")
PYTHON_TERMS = ("python", "django")
REACT_TERMS = ("reactjs", "react.js", "react")
MATCHES = (CITIES_COUNTRIES, PYTHON_TERMS, REACT_TERMS)


def word_in_match(word: str, match: Iterable[str]) -> bool:
    for word_to_match in match:
        if word_to_match in word.lower():
            return True
    return False


def contains_items_from_all(str_to_match: str, matches: Iterable[Iterable[str]]) -> bool:
    results = [False for _ in matches]
    for word in str_to_match.split():
        for i, match in enumerate(matches):
            if not results[i]:
                results[i] = word_in_match(word, match)
    return all(results)


for str_to_match in CONTENT:
    print(contains_items_from_all(str_to_match, MATCHES))
```

## A more efficient approach

```py
def contains_item(str_to_match: str, match: Iterable[str]) -> bool:
    for word_in_match in match:
        if word_in_match in str_to_match:
            return True
    return False


def contains_items_from_all(str_to_match: str, matches: Iterable[Iterable[str]]) -> bool:
    str_to_match = str_to_match.lower()
    results = [False for _ in matches]
    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        if contains_item(str_to_match, match):
            results[i] = True
        else:
            return False
    return all(results)
```

Comment: Hi @m-alorda, thanks for the answer. I just wonder here if `ITEMS_TO_MATCH = react_terms + python_terms + cities_countries` would make sure, that for every variable (react_terms, python_terms & cities_countries) at least one term (for each) is matching. Maybe I missunderstod, but doesn't your code example lead to just one term (of all of them) must match?

Comment: @Joey Coder I just modified the answer explaining why I ignored that case, and giving a possible solution if you really want to match if the item is in all three lists

Comment: @JoeyCoder Noiw that you have provided input data, I have a better idea on what you are trying to do. Let me edit the answer

Comment: @JoeyCoder There you go. Now the script does solve the problem you asked

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's working now as I wanted!